# From Url to Image with Aspose in Java

Tags: java, image, url, aspose.words

I'm working with `aspose` in particular aspose.words, and I 'm using it in order to convert a document (.doc) to a PDF, in Java/JavaFX. Now, I want to convert a simple `url`: www.google.com for example, into a png, or in general an image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can meet this requirement using [Aspose.Words for Java API](http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx). Please use the following code to convert webpage to multi-page TIFF image for example:

```
LoadOptions opts = new LoadOptions();
opts.setLoadFormat(LoadFormat.HTML);
Document doc = new Document("http://www.google.com", opts);
doc.save(getMyDir() + "out.tiff");
```